# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'post_type' (T_STRING) in your code on line 34

Tags: wordpress, post, while-loop, syntax-error

I get a

> Parse error:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'post_type' (T_STRING) in your code on line 34

How can I solve it?
This is my code:

```
if ( $the_service->have_posts() ) : 
    $output .= '
    <div class="single-sidebar-widget">
                <div class="special-links">';
    $output .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs single-services-menu" role="tablist">
                <li><a href="http://example.com/all-services/">All Services</a>
                    </li>   
    while ( $the_service->have_posts() ) : $the_service->the_post(); $count++;              if ( 0 == $post->post_parent )      {               $args1 = array(                 'post_type' => 'services',                  'post_status' => 'publish',                 'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),                   'order'          => esc_attr($order)                );
            if($varPageID == get_the_ID())
            $varClass = 'class=active';
            else
            $varClass = '';

    $output .= '<li role="presentation" '.esc_attr($varClass).'><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
                </li>';

                }
    endwhile;

    $output .= '
    </ul></div></div>';
    else:
        $output .= esc_html( 'Sorry, there is no services under your selected page.', 'plumbing' );
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
echo $output;
?>
```

I have found an error in the while loop in VC widget for custom post type services.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should really work on making your code cleaner, it will help make identifying code errors much easier - as will using an IDE like Sublime, Atom, etc.

Your issue is that right before your `while` loop you have a string that ends with `</li>` but isn't closed, so you need to replace

```
</li>   
while ( $the_service->have_posts() ) : $the_service->the_post(); $count++;
```

with

```
</li>';
while ( $the_service->have_posts() ) : $the_service->the_post(); $count++;
```

## Edit:

You're mix/matching so many different syntaxes and indentations that make it almost impossible to easily screen through your code. I've replaced some of the `if:endif;` loops with brackets, one with a ternary operator, and overall cleaned it up:

```
if( $the_service->have_posts() ){
    $output .= '<div class="single-sidebar-widget">
                    <div class="special-links">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs single-services-menu" role="tablist">
                            <li><a href="http://example.com/all-services/">All Services</a></li>';

    while( $the_service->have_posts() ){
        $the_service->the_post(); $count++;

        if( 0 == $post->post_parent ) {
            $args1 = array(
                'post_type'   => 'services',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                'order'       => esc_attr( $order )
            );

            $varClass = $varPageID == get_the_ID() ? 'class=active' : '';
            $output .= '<li role="presentation" '.esc_attr($varClass).'><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    $output .= '</ul></div></div>';
} else {
    $output .= esc_html( 'Sorry, there is no services under your selected page.', 'plumbing' );
}

wp_reset_postdata();

echo $output;
```